# action after end of loop (perl script)

Tags: perl

Hi This might sound silly, but what I am trying to do is, I want to loop through the array and if it finds the matching pattern in the text file, print md127. otherwise print sda however I don't want it to print sda for each line it cannot find, I only want to print it once and only if it cannot find the matching pattern. Heres the sample of my code:

```
#open output
open (IN, $output) || die "Cannot open the.$output.file";
my @lines = <IN>;
close IN;

for (@lines)
{ 
     if ($_=~ /$find/ )
     {
             #&md127;
             print "md127\n";
     }
     elsif ($_!~ /$find/)
     { 
             print "sda\n";
     }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#open output
open (my $IN, "<", $output) || die "Cannot open the.$output.file";
my @lines = <$IN>;
close $IN;

my $foundIt = 0;
for (@lines)
{ 
     if ($_=~ /$find/ )
     {
             #&md127;
             print "md127\n";
             $foundIt = 1;
     }

}

if (! $foundIt)
{
    print "sda\n";
}
```

Comment: After a successful find you could bail out of the loop with `last;`. That might speed things up a little bit.

Comment: Depends on whether he wants only one "md127". From the question i understood he wanted as many "md127" as there are finds but only a single or none "sda". But yes, if one "md127" is all you need, following `$foundIt = 1;` with a `last;` will get you right out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to set a `$found` variable, set to `0` initially, and set to `1` if you found what you were looking for.

If at the end of the loop, `$found` was `0`, print `"sda"`:

```
$found = 0;
for (@lines)
{ 
     if ($_=~ /$find/ )
     {
             #&md127;
             print "md127\n";
             $found = 1;
     }
}

print "sda\n" unless $found;
```

Comment: You were faster. `print "sda\n" unless $found` though. :)